# SRGS grammars and free-form input in WP 8.1 Speech Recognition

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, speech-recognition, grammar

I want my mobile app to have an ability to recognize some commands in order to navigate between pages. I use SRGS grammar to describe commands with the help of xml file.
For example, to show News page I use such rules:

```
<rule id="top">
<one-of>

  <item>
    <ruleref uri="#newsQuery"/>
    <tag>out.navigation = "News"</tag>
  </item>

</one-of>
```

```
<rule id="newsQuery" scope="public">
<example>Show me news</example>
<item repeat="0-1">Show</item>
<one-of>
  <item>latest news</item>
  <item>news page</item>
  <item>news</item>
  <item>latest news pages</item>
</one-of>
```

It works fine for me. But what should I do if I want to have such command as "Search {something}" where {something} is anything you want and it cannot be created as a rule?

I expect to receive from SpeechRecognitionResult the whole phrase I'll ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the phone you can not mix freeform dictation with grammars as noted at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206964(v=vs.105).aspx)

> A grammar set can contain only one of either a dictation grammar or a
>   web search grammar. Because the dictation and web search grammars
>   perform recognition remotely, you can’t include them in a grammar set
>   that contains grammars that perform recognition locally (as in a list
>   grammar or an SRGS grammar) on the phone.

So for your task you can simply choose either dictation or web search grammar for the whole utterance. I would not worry about being able to recognize "search" in the beginning, the rest is way more important anyway. You can activate dictation grammar with [AddGrammarFromPredefinedType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.phone.speech.recognition.speechgrammarset.addgrammarfrompredefinedtype.aspx)